# Voip Enabled iOS app stops when killed from background. Is this the expected behaviour

Tags: ios

I have a requirement where the app have to be in the background always. From my research What I found is that VOIP is the best option. This app will not be submitted to app store, so the apple guidelines can be ignored. My question is:
- Will this app get killed if a user manually swipes of it from the background?
- Is there any way that I can restart/relaunch this type of app if it gets killed.

Comment: You can try to notify the user with a local notification to launch the app when the user kills the background of the particular app. This will be a good solution

Comment: Thanks @Chan, But the user must manually touch the notification in order to launch the app (This is my understanding, not sure if there is any other way). That means until he touches the notification the app will be suspended.